# Trying to display scoring results in a survey "thank you" email

Tags: qualtrics

I'm making a survey and 5 categories are being scored. I want to display these results in the post-survey thank you email but when I try to include the scores using embedded data fields they do not show up. What can I do to make them appear in the thank you email? (See screenshots)

[image: What I put in the saved message]

[image: What appears in the email]

In the Data and Analysis tab I can tell that the scores are being counted, so I know the scoring is functional. What I can't do is get them to appear in the email.